# i can't run my Android Studio project - it shows me Manifest merger failed with multiple errors

Tags: android

This is my android.manifest file. I searched a lot of things here but my problem is not solved yet. What can I do?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.example.e_healthcareapp" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.EHealthcareApp"
    tools:targetApi="31" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="false"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_register_option" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Login_options"
        android:exported="false"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Registration"
        android:exported="false"
        android:label="Registration Form"
        android:parentActivityName=".Registration" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity2"
        android:exported="false"
        android:label="Log in Form"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity2" /> <!-- back button values -->
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        tools:ignore="DuplicateActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

this is my build.gradle(module:appname)

Comment: Can you post more of the error message

Comment: what is exact error you are getting. share manifest if are having more than one manifest files

Comment: i don't know where the problem is because my emulator is also not starting so i can't found the error whenever i click to start emulator it seems just targeted devies are coming online and that notification stucks

Comment: You have added .MainActivity twice in manifest

Answer (score 0):

In your Manifest, you can choose between Text and Merged Manifest (in Android Studio below your Manifest).
Click on Merged Manifest and there is a detailed description of your error.